# How to make a globally accessible nodejs cli

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to make my `cli.js` file a global cli:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

// ----------------------------------
// CLI
//
// Command line tool
// ----------------------------------

var program = require('commander');
var lib = require('../lib'); // <--- This may be an issue

program
  .version('0.0.1')
  .usage('<cmd>')
  .parse(process.argv);

console.log('Running');
```

I'm including this file in my `package.json`:

```
...
"bin": {"cli":"./bin/cli.js"}
..
```

After running `npm install` I can link the bin file, but I cannot *run* it globally. What I mean by that is, if I go to another directory and run

`$ cli`

Not only are the relative paths invalid (I need to inject the `lib` dependency), I need to link the file again.

Just to clarify, this is what I'm trying to achieve:

1. Include local project dependencies via relative path
2. Link the project globally
3. Use the project in other files (or have it installed on an entirely new machine) and have the dependencies intact.

How do libraries like Grunt and Gulp manage to provide a globally available command line interface? Please help!

Comment: Tried to install it where these global CLI packages are installed with NPM? Because when you install with `-g` you have those files installed somewhere on your HDD.

Comment: do you have your code online? So I can have a look and understand what is wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use relative paths directly, instead I use [nodejs global objects](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_global_objects) with relative paths;

- process.cwd()
- __filename
- __dirname

It may depends on your project specific need what is required when. In my project [stubb-db](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/StubbyDB) I use [config builder](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/StubbyDB/blob/master/os/nushi/stubbydb/configbuilder.js) to build all the paths in advanced before using them.

Comment: Ah!! I believe I took your question in wrong way, it's not about loading relative resources but code itself. let me find out something useful.